# Regarding GFCI outlets

Tags: electrical, gfci

When a GFCI outlet trips, does it open both the hot and the neutral, or only the hot?  An outlet beyond the GFCI outlet has an open neutral and I wonder if that is normal when a GFCI trips?

Comment: If your testing device is a 3-light tester, it may not have an open neutral at all.  The legends are often laughably wrong.

Comment: A outlet tester requires power. If the outlet tester has power you have reset the GFCI feeding it so there should not be an open neutral. But I agree with Harper some of those testers are such a joke I think his magic 8 ball comparison is accurate.

Answer (score 2):

The neutral in a GFCI may not open when it trips. So if you are reading an open neutral, that could very well be part of the reason it tripped.

[image]

Comment: I would like to know the reason for a down vote (reversed) on a correct answer. There has been a lot of these lately.

Comment: @EdBeal, not the down voter, but it's a very short answer?  I don't know, that's all I can think of. (And this still has a down vote - a high rep user like you can click on the number and see the up and down votes)

Comment: @EdBeal -- I'm pretty sure this answer is *not* correct, actually -- if you look at the reference schematic in any GFCI-chip datasheet, it shows that the breaker breaks both hot and neutral, and that comports with the GFCI/RCD teardowns I've seen as well

Comment: Try and look a few up and provide a reference. I can start with the NEC exhibit 210.6 it shows the shunt trip on the hot and nothing on the neutral. This plus the one he already posted from the web.

Comment: @EdBeal see page 4 [here](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/RV4145A-D.pdf) or page 6 [here](http://www.idea2ic.com/GFI/LM1851.pdf), as well as the photos from [this teardown link](https://www.powerelectronictips.com/teardown-leviton-ground-fault-circuit-interrupter/)

Comment: To all - I really didn't think that such a small post would create so much comment. I posted the schematic to show that the neutral fed through a coil in the GFCI device, but did not disconnect. Then reading everyone's comments, it sort of got my head scratching. So I went ahead and got my meter, went over to a GFCI Receptacle in the kitchen and began to take readings. The result is that the neutral and ground rang through when the device was in active and in tripped condition. So the device did not open the neutral or the ground in tripped position. Hope this puts everyone's mind at ease.

Comment: Three phase so we both have examples that it can be done differently, but that still dosenot explain a down vote for an answer that has multiple examples of it being correct including the one in the NEC. I have checked 3 different brands / styles now and 2 do not break the neutral 1 did. All that is required is the hot so if someone would have stated the reason for the down vote there would not be all this, to tell the truth I have started reversing down votes that have no reason if the answer sounds plausible.

Comment: @EdBeal -- edited and undownvoted

Answer (score 2):

At least three sources indicate that a GFCI outlet interrupts **both** the hot and the neutral.

[The Circuit Detective](http://thecircuitdetective.com/gfis.php):

> When a GFI outlet trips off, both the hot and neutral "line" terminals become disconnected inside the receptacle from the "load" terminals.

[WaterHeaterTime.org](http://waterheatertimer.org/pdf/GFCI-troubleshooting.pdf):

> More importantly, a GFCI receptacle switches off both the hot and neutral sides when it trips; making sure that the hot leg is interrupted even if it was mistakenly attached to the neutral side of the receptacle.

[PDH Online](https://pdhonline.com/courses/e321/e321content.pdf):

> GFCI are generally designed to interrupt both conductors in case someone has
>   mistakenly wired a circuit backwards and is using the white conductor as the hot conductor instead of the black conductor.

And this source indicates that "it depends".

[Voltimum](https://www.voltimum.com.au/content/rcbo-2-pole-and-1pn):

> Essentially RCBO's are classified by the number of poles and current paths:
>
> - 1P+N Single pole RCBO with one overcurrent protected pole and uninterrupted neutral (two current paths)
> - 1P+N Two pole RCBO with one overcurrent protected pole and an unprotected switched neutral pole
> - 2P Two pole RCBO with two overcurrent protected poles

Bottom line:
Probable, but inconclusive. You'd need to find the spec sheet of your particular model to be certain.

Comment: In the last quote, from Voltimum, the 1P+N is defined twice. I think the first definition is for 1P.

Comment: I'm just relaying what their site said, so I can't be certain. But I think the first two are two different flavors of 1P+N.

Comment: Indeed, it appears to be describing two flavours of the 1P+N, i.e switched vs not-switched neutral. It's confusing they're named the same.